# Right way to access Java Singleton private members

Tags: java, singleton

If you have a Java Singleton that looks like this:

```
public class MySingleton {

private static MySingleton instance;

private int member;

public static MySingleton getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance = new MySingleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

private MySingleton(){
    //empty private constructor
}

public int getMemberA(){
    return member;
}

public int getMemberB(){
    return instance.member;
}

}
```

...is there a difference between getMemberA and getMemberB? That is, is there a difference between accessing the member with `instance.xxx` and just `xxx`?

Note: I am aware of the pros and cons of using the Singleton pattern!

Comment: I have but wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.

Your singleton implementation isn't currently threadsafe, which means it's possible to call `getMemberB()` on an instance *other than* the one referred to by `instance`, at which point you'll get a different result.

If your implementation were thread-safe (so genuinely only one instance could ever be created) then they'd be equivalent, and the simpler form would be much preferred.

Comment: What is your preferred approach? [This seems nice to me.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh)

Comment: @hooby3dfx: It depends on your requirements. The nested class approach is more hassle than it's worth unless you really need ultra-lazy instantiation and other static methods. The enum approach has its benefits. Personally I try to avoid the singleton pattern in the first place, so it rarely comes up for me...

Answer (score 4):

No functional difference, but I find `getMemberA()` easier on the eye.

Note that your singleton isn't thread-safe. Two threads calling `getInstance()` concurrently could result in the creation of two objects. If this happens, the singleton contract is broken, and all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

No difference in behavior, however, I'd rather use 'return member' or even 'return this.member' as this looks more intuitively.

Thread-safety is a completely different topic and this simple singleton does not meet any thread-safe singleton requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of Singleton pattern uses lazy load technique. But it is not thread safe. We can use the `synchronized` keyword to make `getInstance()` method thread safe, but it hurts performance. It's better that we make double-check on private singleton member.

```
public class MySingleton {

    private volatile static MySingleton instance;

    public static MySingleton getInstance(){
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MySingleton(){
        //empty private constructor
    }
}
```